# Switch case taking array item instead of strict values

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why it is that you can not use `array[index]` in a switch case.

I stumbled upon this while making a simple settings read/write class and it had me a bit confused for a while as the debugger told me that all values was correct.

Example one, this code does not work:

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
foreach(String line in lines) {
    String[] args = line.Split(':');
    switch(args[0]) {
        case "Version":
            Version = args[1].Trim();
            break;
        case "Run Local":
            RunLocal = (args[1].Trim().ToLower() == "true") ? true : false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Example two, please note that I use a `String val = args[0]` before the switch

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
foreach(String line in lines) {
    String[] args = line.Split(':');
    String val = args[0];
    switch(val) {
        case "Version":
            Version = args[1].Trim();
            break;
        case "Run Local":
            RunLocal = (args[1].Trim().ToLower() == "true") ? true : false;
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

There seem to be a bit of confusion, so I've updated the code examples to show the entire method and I will try to elaborate a bit.

When using args[0] in my switch, it does not match the value with any of the cases despite actually being identical (I refer to the attached image of the inspector). The code basically just carries on as if no match was found.

I have settigns.txt where I simply read all files with `File.ReadAllLines(filePath)`. This settings file look like this:

```
Version: 0
Run Local: true
```

Images of the inspector:

[image]

Comment: when you say "does not work" - what do you *mean* by that? what happens? you absolutely can use an array indexer when evaluating switch expressions...

Comment: [Constant expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#constant-pattern) in `switch` statement should perfectly work. What is coming in `args`? Maybe you have a quotes or spaces in a string?

Comment: I've just tested with [this](https://gist.github.com/mgravell/d3f516642b0071c429659a9418611b75) - it works fine; if I run `(the exe) Version 91` it outputs 91 as the version; it isn't a great command-line API, I'll grant you, but it works fine in terms of the `switch` test. So: do you have a similar minimal repro that shows it *not working* (along with the command-line that you're using when it doesn't work)

Comment: I've added a bit more information to my question, I hope this clears up a few of your questions

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thing is tho, the value is correct, as I explained in my example, If i put args[0] into a String val, and evalue val, the code works as expected.

Comment: @SimonJensen can you the complete example of file? Is there any EOL symbols?

Comment: If I run your example, it works fine (as it should). That means it's not a minimal reproducible example - either there's something weird going on in the context (e.g. `args` actually being a captured variable used in a multi-threaded scenario or something), or something weird about your .NET runtime (which are you using?).

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that is the entire settings.txt file, its a direct copy and paste.

Comment: @Luaan .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: If you can reproduce this in a compilable console app, please post the code. Otherwise nobody will be able to reproduce it, because the code you've given will work unless there's something else going on.